# EF Core/SQL Server include navigation properties only work when used directly in query

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

My environment: VS 2017, EF Core (2.1.4), SQL Server 2017, eager loading

When I build my query like this:

```
var query = MyDbSet.Where(c => c.CustomerId > 2).Include(c => c.Addresses);
var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

I have my desired navigation property (Addresses) in the resulting entity.
But when I do this:

```
var intermediate = MyDbSet.Where(c => c.CustomerId > 2);
var query = intermediate.Include(c => c.Addresses);
var result = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

The result comes without a properly filled Addresses property (it is null).

I am developing a generic abstraction layer and want to allow the user to provide a list of include statements. I want to iterate over those statements and add them one by one.

In my unit test environment it works like I expect (using sqlite) but in production (SQL Server) the query is not properly filled. Any idea what's going on here?

How can I do something like this in SQL Server environment:

```
foreach (var expression in includes)
    query = query.Include(expression);
```

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: It's working either way. There must be something else - for instance `query.Select(…)` or something.

Comment: @IvanStoev When I debug the statements I immediately see the results differ. Even before Select statements.

Comment: Chaining `Include`s  is proved to work. I was referring to [Ignored Includes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#ignored-includes). Expanding the intermediate results in the debugger might have side effects, because of the context tracking and navigation property fix-up process .  Always check the final results. Note that sometimes EF Core might load data you didn't ask for. I'm pretty sure your `Include`s are ignored in both cases. To prove that, add `optionsBuilder.ConfigureWarnings(warnings => warnings.Throw(CoreEventId.IncludeIgnoredWarning));`.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for this. I was actually also calling FirstOrDefault() but forgot to mention that. I've updated my question.

Comment: @RobVermeulen `Include()` works. You say you're trying to build a "generic" abstraction layer though which means the code is probably not what you posted here. The actual entities and context definition are missing so people can't guess what could be the problem. Adding `Include` after `Where()` is definitely strange though. BTW EF *is* that abstraction layer.

Comment: @RobVermeulen you can log the queries generated by EF to see what's actually being generated and executed. Check [Logging SQL and Change-Tracking Events in EF Core](https://msdn.microsoft.com/magazine/mt830355)

Comment: @RobVermeulen any luck yet?